# Storyboard list data demo, how to check condition back to list segue

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am new ios, i use storyboard to implement list data function demo, include add data.
In my AddWrokLogViewController,I have a method (IBAction)done:(id)sender bind + button.
as follow, in my do function, I want to check user inputs and save user input datas by http post. when post data in remote save success, I want go back to list view.

as before I search apple article introduction storyboard, but in this demo, when user tap add button,direct transfer to list page view :http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH1-SW1

If I use AFHTTPClient to save data in remote server success, then go back to list page view, or still in add page view and display error message.

any one can give me some suggestions, thanks!

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",api_createworklog];
NSDictionary *params=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:uname,@"loginname",token,@"token",beginTime
                      ,@"beginTime",content,@"content",address,@"address",projectNameTemp,@"projectName"
                      ,workType,@"workType",workDate,@"workDate",validDate,@"validDate", nil];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];
[client postPath:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *responseString = [operation responseString];
    NSDictionary *data = [responseString objectFromJSONStringWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionLooseUnicode];
    NSString *sysCode = [data objectForKey:@"syscode"];
    NSString *businessCode = [data objectForKey:@"businesscode"];
    if(sysCode != nil && ![sysCode isEqualToString:@""] && businessCode != nil && ![businessCode isEqualToString:@""]){
        if([sysCode isEqualToString:ws_access_success] && [businessCode isEqualToString:ws_access_success]){
            //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            addSuccess = true;
        } else{
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"添加失败"                                                            message:responseString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSString *responseString = operation.responseString;
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"访问服务器异常，添加失败！"                                                            message:responseString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
}];
```

Comment: Can you more clearly articulate (a) what the app is currently doing; and (b) what you want it to do? I do not understand what what precisely the question is. I notice that you have commented out the `popViewControllerAnimated`. So, assuming your segue to this view controller was a push segue, I would have thought that this code would work fine (if you uncommented that line). Bottom line, what's not working?

Comment: Thanks for you answer my question.Now i solve my question.I remove embed navigation controller before my addControllerView Page, and change segue type to push, then uncommented out the popViewControllerAnimated. the Add button submit transfer ok. Thanks, excuse me for not well.

Comment: That makes sense. Glad you solved your problem. And no need to apologize for your English. I wish my command of my second languages was half as good as yours! I meant no offense.